# Why do newlines within parenthesis change arithmetic results?

Tags: ruby, operators, newline

Why do the following expressions resolve the way they do? Brackets should have higher precedence than newlines, shouldn't they?

```
3 - ( 1 + 1 )
# => 1

3 - ( 1
     + 1 )
# => 2
```

Omitting the plus also lets the expression evaluate to `2`:

```
3 - ( 1
      1 )
# => 2
```

If I declare as a continuous newline (escaped) or move the plus to the first line, desired behavior is achieved:

```
3 - ( 1 \
     + 1 )
# => 1

3 - ( 1 +
      1 )
# => 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because Ruby recognizes a new line as an end of an expression unless the expression is incomplete. For example,

```
(1
+ 1)
```

is the same as

```
(1;
+1)
```

which is the same as `+1` since the last expression within the parentheses is returned. And that is further the same as `1`.

When you have a `+` at the end of a line, the expression is incomplete, and hence continues to the next line. That makes:

```
3 - ( 1 +
      1 )
```

to be interpreted as `3 - (1 + 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have code in the brackets then every line will be threat as separated code line of code if you won't end it with `\` or start new one with math operator.

So in your example:

```
def plus_minus_if_you_understand_this_the_problem_is_solved_i_guess 
    3 - (1
         1 )
end
```

Means I have number `3` and want to subtract expression in brackets. In the brackets I have line #1 number `1` and in #2 line number `1` again and as it's last line of expression it's retuned by Ruby (like in `def` last item before `end` is returned. So:

```
( 3   # doing nothing
  1 ) # returns 1
```

Also take a look bellow. Again, this part of code returns `2` as it is the last item in brackets:

```
( puts "hello!"
  2 ) => 2
```